# Using non-wordpress PHP pages on the same ftp server

Tags: php, wordpress

I have Wordpress site set up on the route of my ftp server, I am trying to add [PressKit()](http://dopresskit.com/) to my site in the directory /Press . This uses an index.php file to display the html, however wordpress seems to show a 404 error when trying to access it. I have tried adding a .htaccess to the subdirectory, but with no luck.

I'm wondering how to prevent the 404 error from displaying? As I am certain the page is there, as a few times when I use the full url (including index.php) it will open, but only on my machine.

Apologies if this is simple, web dev isn't really my field.

Cheers.

Edit: Works now, but case sensitive

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

# Include in the next line all folders to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(Press) [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Could you paste your main .htaccess?

Comment: added .htaccess to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `.htaccess` file, in the root of your WordPress installation (not the sub-folder), and look for the `#BEGIN WORDPRESS` block. You can replace it with this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

# Include in the next line all folders to exclude
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(Press|folder2) [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

You can add more folders for WordPress to ignore, using the pipe `|` where you currently see the words `Press|folder2`. You may also remove the "folder2" reference, that's just an example

Comment: Hi, I saw your edit in the question. So this does in-fact work now?